# Hot Network Questions feed shows duplicates for questions that have been renamed

Tags: bug, hot-questions, feed, permalink

When I subscribe to https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions using feedly.com I sometimes see questions more than once in my feed. I suspect this is because when questions titles are changed the target URL also changes.

For example, my feedly feed shows two entries for question 59167 with slightly different `id` values:

- `https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/59167/why-are-masks-a-political-topic-in-the-us`
- `https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/59167/why-are-mask-mandates-a-political-topic-in-the-us`

I'm not an expert on rss/atom feeds but I suspect the problem is that the entry's `id` field is expected to be unique and **permanent**.

> id
> --
>
> Identifies the entry using a universally unique and permanent URI. Suggestions on how to make a good id can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20081225232147/http://diveintomark.org/archives/2004/05/28/howto-atom-id). Two entries in a feed can have the same value for id if they represent the same entry at different points in time.
>
> -- [w3 atom documentation](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/atom.html#requiredEntryElements)

I'd humbly suggest using the permalink for the `id` or even a non-URL URI that just uses the question's numeric ID that never changes. Perhaps even better would be to follow the advice for generating the atom id on https://web.archive.org/web/20081225232147/http://diveintomark.org/archives/2004/05/28/howto-atom-id which would end up with something like `tag:politics.stackexchange.com,2020-10-20:/q/59167`

Comment: I dont see how your example illustrates the problem, as there is only one entry.

Comment: @Gran, the *suggestions link* advises: "Why you shouldn’t use your permalink as an Atom ID".

Comment: @Rob - good point, i hadn't read that. permalink seems like a strict improvement but i've added the point about using their "tag:" scheme instead.